# Find the conditional density function given two exponential random variables.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent exponential random variables with respective rates $\lambda$ and $\mu$, where $\lambda > \mu$ and let $c>0$. I need to find the conditional density function of $X$ given that $X + Y=c$. Here is what I have $$f(X=x|X+Y=c)=\frac{f(X=x,X+Y=c)}{f(X+Y=c)}$$
$$=\frac{f(X=x,Y=c-x)}{f(X+Y=c)}$$
$$=\frac{f(X=x)f(Y=c-x)}{f(X+Y=c)}$$

I got the last step by knowing $X$ and $Y$ are independent. I'm a little unsure that the second step I did is valid where I changed $X+Y=c$ into $Y=c-x$. If those parts are both correct, my only issue is the pdf of $X+Y$. I think that it is Gamma, but I'm not sure about the parameterization.

Comment: This would have been fine for discrete distributions $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: The density function for $X+Y$ can be found using convolution (since they are independent).

Comment: @DouglasMolin so doing the convolution I'm able to find that $f_{X+Y}(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda-\mu}\mu e^{-\mu t}+\frac{\mu}{\mu-\lambda}\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ but according to the previous comment, is there an error in the conditioning process that I'm using?

Comment: If you mean to say $f(X+Y=c)=P(X+Y=c)$, then it is obviously zero. I was a little distracted by your notation that's all.

Comment: I don't want it to be $P(X+Y=c)$ I don't think because I'm trying to find the density function. I know the answer is supposed to be $\frac{(\lambda-\mu)e^{-(\lambda-\mu)x}}{1-e^{-(\lambda-\mu)c}}$

Comment: Of course it is not the probability, but the density $f_{X+Y}$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so what I have done is okay? It would be better if I write it as $\frac{f_X(X=x)\cdot f_Y(Y=c-x)}{f_{X+Y}(X+Y=c)}$

Comment: $f_{X|Z}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}$ is what you have rom definition where $Z=X+Y$

Comment: Your approach is correct though.